# Can't see any changes in nohup.out

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, centos, nohup

I have a python script that I run on a server with this command:

```
sudo nohup python fetch_script.py &
```

It creates a `nohup.out` file on the same directory.

After a few days I came back and tried to check it, I did:

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

It gave me a result:

```
root@xx-xxx-xxx-xx:/home/ubuntu# tail -f nohup.out 
8809896
8809897
8809898
8809899
8809900
8809901
8809902
8809903
8809904
8809905
```

I waited a little bit but nothing happend. The script supposed to send messages to the RabbitMQ and update count and print it. The script was running the whole time, I know for sure, because I could see new messages where coming constantly. But `nohup.out` stuck. I also checked it with `ls -l` command to see if the size changed, but still no luck.
Do you know what could be the reason for that? I assume that it will be eventually updated but don't know how long it would take. So are there any ways to constantly update this file? Will `nice -20` help in this case?

## UPDATE

Just rotate the Log, with `/usr/sbin/logrotate` waited a bit and saw changes in fresh `nohup.out`

Comment: are you sure the process is still running?

Comment: The process is running, and the script is running also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nohup.out` file is written directly by the program that is being run under `nohup`, just like with normal shell redirection. If it's not being updated the problem is with the Python program, not with `nohup` itself.

Comment: Do you know if the file (`nohup.out`) will become large like 1G, could it be the problem of delay that I see in output?

Comment: It's more probable that the python process just decided to flush its output buffer to disk. What often happens with programs is that if their output is connected to an interactive terminal their output is line-buffered, so that every time that a line is written it is flushed to the output, but if the program is run with stdout redirected to a file it is block-buffered and the output file is updated less frequently.